# Assembly Fat32 Booting

Tags: assembly, x86, kernel, nasm, bootloader

So after hours of strugling I'm now completely lost.
What I'm trying to do is basically load the first root directory entry into memory, but it seems it fails at the reading part. I'm using virtualbox to emulate!

And here is the hole code:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]
jmp     START
nop

OEM_ID              db "APACU-OS" 
BytesPerSector      dw 0x0200
SectorsPerCluster   db 0x01
ReservedSectors     dw 0x227E
TotalFATs           db 0x02
MaxRootEntries      dw 0x0000
NumberOfSectors     dw 0x0000
MediaDescriptor     db 0xF8
SectorsPerFAT       dw 0x0000
SectorsPerTrack     dw 0x003D
SectorsPerHead      dw 0x0002
HiddenSectors       dd 0x00000001
TotalSectors        dd 0x00200000
BigSectorsPerFAT    dd 0x00003EC1
Flags               dw 0x0000
FSVersion           dw 0x0000
RootDirectoryStart  dd 0x00000002
FSInfoSector        dw 0x0001
BackupBootSector    dw 0x0006
times 12 db 0
DriveNumber         db 0x80
db 0x00
Signature           db 0x29
VolumeID            dd 0xFFFFFFFF
VolumeLabel         db "APACU BOOT "
SystemID            db "FAT32   "

 START:
 mov Byte[DriveNumber], dl
 ; code located at 0000:7C00, adjust segment registers
      cli
      mov     ax, 0x7C00
      mov     ds, ax
      mov     es, ax
      mov     fs, ax
      mov     gs, ax
 ; create stack
      mov     ax, 0x7C00
      mov     ss, ax
      mov     sp, 0xFFFF
      sti



  mov ah, 0x41
  mov dl, [DriveNumber]
  mov bx, 0x55AA
  int 0x13
  jnc continue
  mov ah, 0x0E
  mov al, "N"
  int 0x10
  ;int 0x18
  ; No Support For Extended Reading

  continue:

  ; size of a cluster in sectors is stored in cx 
      mov    cx,  WORD[SectorsPerCluster]


 ; compute location of the begining of the Data area and store in ax
      mov     al, BYTE [TotalFATs]                ; Total number of FATs
      mul     WORD[BigSectorsPerFAT]                ; Number of sectors for a FAT
      add     ax, WORD [ReservedSectors]          ; Find the start of the Data area
      mov     WORD [datasector], ax               ; Store the begining of the Data area



 ; read 1st data cluster into memory (7C00:0200)
      mov     ax, WORD[RootDirectoryStart]
      call ClusterLBA
      mov     bx, 0x0200                          ; copy 1st data cluter above bootcode
      call    ReadSectors

 ; Point Index register to 1st File Entry
      mov     di, 0x0200 + 0x20                         




      mov     si, msgCRLF
      call    DisplayMessage

  ;Point to the offset where the file location information contains

      mov     dx, WORD [di + 0x001A]
      mov     WORD [cluster], dx                  






;Set up the segments where the kernel needs to be loaded

        mov ax, 0100h       ; set ES:BX = 0100:0000
        mov es, ax          
        mov bx, 0           

;Read the cluster which contains the kernel
        mov cx, 0x0008  
        mov ax, WORD[cluster]
        call ClusterLBA
        call ReadSectors





      mov     si, msgCRLF
      call    DisplayMessage

;Jump to the location where the kernel was loded

      push    WORD 0x0100
      push    WORD 0x0000
      retf




;An error has occured if this part is executed
      mov     si, msgFailure
      call    DisplayMessage
      mov     ah, 0x00
      int     0x16                                ; await keypress
      int     0x19                                ; warm boot computer







 ;*************************************************************************
 ; PROCEDURE ReadSectors
 ; reads cx sectors from disk starting at ax into
 ;memory location es:bx
 ;*************************************************************************
 ReadSectors:
 .MAIN:
      mov     di, 0x0005                          ; five retries for error
 .SECTORLOOP:
      push    ax
      push    bx
      push    cx
      call    LBACHS
      mov     ah, 0x02                            ; BIOS read sector
      mov     al, 0x01                            ; read one sector
      mov     ch, BYTE [absoluteTrack]            ; track
      mov     cl, BYTE [absoluteSector]           ; sector
      mov     dh, BYTE [absoluteHead]             ; head
      mov     dl, BYTE [DriveNumber]              ; drive
      int     0x13                                ; invoke BIOS
      jnc     .SUCCESS                ; test for read error

      xor     ax, ax                              ; BIOS reset disk
      int     0x13                                ; invoke BIOS
      dec     di                                  ; decrement error counter
      pop     cx
      pop     bx
      pop     ax
      jnz     .SECTORLOOP                         ; attempt to read again
      int 0x18
 .SUCCESS:
      mov     si, msgProgress
      call    DisplayMessage
      pop     cx
      pop     bx
      pop     ax
      add     bx, WORD [BytesPerSector]           ; queue next buffer
      inc     ax                                  ; queue next sector
      loop    .MAIN                               ; read next sector
      ret


 ;*************************************************************************
 ; PROCEDURE DisplayMessage
 ; display ASCIIZ string at ds:si via BIOS
 ;*************************************************************************
 DisplayMessage:
      lodsb                                       ; load next character
      or      al, al                              ; test for NUL character
      jz      .DONE
      mov     ah, 0x0E                            ; BIOS teletype
      mov     bh, 0x00                            ; display page 0
      mov     bl, 0x07                            ; text attribute
      int     0x10                                ; invoke BIOS
      jmp     DisplayMessage
 .DONE:
      ret

 ;*************************************************************************



 ;*************************************************************************
 ; PROCEDURE ClusterLBA
 ; convert FAT cluster into LBA addressing scheme
 ; FileStartSector = ((X - 2) * SectorsPerCluster(0x08))
 ;*************************************************************************
 ClusterLBA:
      sub     ax, 0x0002                          ; zero base cluster number
      xor     cx, cx
      mov     cl, BYTE [SectorsPerCluster]        ; convert byte to word
      mul     cx
      add     ax, WORD [datasector]               ; base data sector
      ret

 ;*************************************************************************
 ; PROCEDURE LBACHS
 ; convert ax LBA addressing scheme to CHS addressing scheme
 ; absolute sector = (logical sector / sectors per track) + 1
 ; absolute head   = (logical sector / sectors per track) MOD number of heads
 ; absolute track  = logical sector / (sectors per track * number of heads)
 ;*************************************************************************
 LBACHS:
  mov word[SectorsPerTrack], 0x003D
  mov word[SectorsPerHead], 0x0002

  xor     dx, dx                              ; prepare dx:ax for operation
  div     WORD [SectorsPerTrack]              ; calculate
  inc     dl                                  ; adjust for sector 0
  mov     BYTE [absoluteSector], dl
  xor     dx, dx                              ; prepare dx:ax for operation
  div     WORD [SectorsPerHead]                     ; calculate
  mov     BYTE [absoluteHead], dl
  mov     BYTE [absoluteTrack], al
  ret
  ;************************************************************************

 absoluteSector db 0x00
 absoluteHead   db 0x00
 absoluteTrack  db 0x00

 cluster     dw 0x0000
 datasector  dw 0x0000

;*******************************************************************************
;messages that needs to be shown

 msgProgress db ".", 0x00
 msgFailure  db 0x0D, 0x0A, "Kernel loading failed...", 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00
 msgCRLF     db 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00

      TIMES 510-($-$$) DB 0
      DW 0xAA55
 ;*************************************************************************
```

I know it is failing because it is triggering int 0x18 in the read sectors loop.

**So my question: Why is it failing? And how would I go about fixing it? And also do I need to use BIOS extended read drive?**

Comment: That’s a lot of code; can you point to the specific part you need help on?  Additionally, how do you know your kernel is failing?  What is the output from VirtualBox?

Comment: It is failing in the ReadSectors because is it triggering the int 0x18 in the end of it.

Comment: Not even close. Attempting to save `dl` before setting up segregs is an error, and for `org 0x7C00`, you want segregs to be zero. There may be other problems.

Comment: I've ran into issues with VirtualBox which were later confirmed to me by a then-Sun engineer in real life. Please use anything else, even BOCHS is better and more reliable, but I'm particular to qemu now due to the ability to attach gdb and b *0x7C00 for this. Also, what @FrankKotler said.

Comment: You detected drive extensions in int 0x13, so why aren't you using them to perform the read instead?  By using CHS rather than LBA you aren't saving time; in fact, you're wasting code space.  As Frank mentioned, there may be other problems and I think you're BPB is questionable.  Have you used a disk editor to test it out on a USB key?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use boot hook interrupt (int 0x18) like this.And I think that is not your own  code.If you want use clear bootloader,You have to use binary files (which is using in other operating systems).If you want to make your own bootloader,you have to waste a lot of time for coding and compiling and placing.

Answer (score 0):

For [Segment:Offset]
RealMemory = Segment * 16 + Offset

The boot sector loads at 0x07C00 in real memory.  This equates to either 07C0:0000 or 0000:7C00.  So first, you need to decide in which space you want to reference your variables.  It looks like you had set the origin to 0x7C00.

However you are setting the segment registers to 7C00. For the origin you selected, the segment value would be 0.  If you select [org 0], then the segment value is 0x07C0, though.
Further, you have to align CS:IP to correspond with the address space you have selected for the code.

if origin is 0x7c00:

```
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    push word RealignmentPoint
    retf

RealignmentPoint:

    ;variable addresses are mapped into 'usable' memory locations.
```

Still that isn't the best practice.  Setting the origin to 0 and the segment register to 0x07C0 allows us to reference near variables with a single byte, and the realignment code is as follows.

```
    mov ax, 0x07C0
    mov ds, ax
    push ax
    push word RealignmentPoint
    retf

RealignmentPoint:

    ;variable addresses are mapped into acceptable memory locations
```

That technique is part of the disassembly of the NTFS boot sector (fine print be damned).  But you need to do more research and plan things out better or otherwise the other 98% of the code you're trying to write won't work either because it's based on deprecated functionality or incomplete logic.